# Keyboard shortcut for previous window of an application

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcut is for "Move focus to next window" is normally bound to
`cmd+backtick` or `cmd+<` (depending on keyboard layout).

In the case of multiple open windows I often go one window too far.

Is there a "Move focus to *previous* window"?

FWIW my keyboard layout:
[image]

Comment: On a French keyboard, ⇧⌘` does move focus to previous window in most apps for me, except in Finder, where it does something else.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts. Press '+', select Application: All Applications, to 'Menu Title' type in 'Move focus to previous window'. Assign shortcut you want. If you want to change 'move to next window', it's already under 'Keyboard' with name 'Move focus to next window'

Comment: This does not work on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Tested under macOS 11.2.3 (Big Sur), JIS Keyboard and `Terminal.app`.

1. Open `System Preferences.app`
2. Click `Keyboard` and switch to the `Shortcuts` tab
3. In the left pane, select `Keyboard`
4. In the right pane, select `Move focus to next window` and assign any shortcut you want.

Now you can move focus to previous window by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> plus the assigned keyboard shortcut. For example, if you've assigned <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the final step, then you can move focus to previous window by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: `Move focus to next window` is properly mapped, but pressing it while holding shift does nothing. This does not work, either.

Comment: @MartinBraun I re-tested in 2023 today on M1 mac Ventura, and the answer still worked at least for iTerm2.app and Firefox.app.

Answer (score 0):

cmd+shift+backtick takes you one window back

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Which command is your shortcut bound to?